# Create new model instance with one to one and foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-models

Model:

```
class BurrowedBook(models.Model):
    # Fields
    borrow_date = models.DateField()
    return_date = models.DateField()
    actual_return_date = models.DateField(null=True)

    # Relationship Fields
    book_copy = models.OneToOneField(BookCopy)
    burrowed_by = models.ForeignKey(Member)
```

Save new instance:

```
member = Member.objects.filter(member_id=memberId)
book_copy = BookCopy.objects.filter(book=book, copy_number=book_copy_id)

BurrowedBook.objects.create(borrow_date=borrow_date, 
                              return_date=return_date, 
                              book_copy=book_copy, burrowed_by=member)
```

How do I save a new instance of this model? I'm having trouble with one to one field and foreign key field.

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot assign "<QuerySet []>": "BurrowedBook.book_copy" must be a 
"BookCopy" instance.
```

Comment: You need to show more context. What is `book_copy` in that second snippet? The error implies it is an empty queryset, so where does it come from?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The error appear because you're trying to assign a queryset `Cannot assign "<QuerySet []>"` to solve your problem you have to use get, that return a single object and not a queryset

```
member = Member.objects.get(member_id=memberId)
book_copy = BookCopy.objects.get(book=book, copy_number=book_copy_id)
```

Another option would be get the first object from the queryset:

```
book_copy = BookCopy.objects.filter(book=book, copy_number=book_copy_id)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error says, you have to hava a BookCopy instance and assign that instance to your book_copy. You have to create a BookCopy first(need to check your BookCopy model), like -> book_copy = BookCopy.objects.create(). And in terms of saving the instance, check this for detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#create